# How to avoid duplicating multiple type parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have several generic types which I need to use with the same type parameters:

```
type Type1<A, B, C> = ...;
type Type2<A, B, C> = ...;
type Type3<A, B, C> = ...;

f(x: Type1<ComplexParam1, ComplexParam2, ComplexParam3>) {
  const y: Type2<ComplexParam1, ComplexParam2, ComplexParam3> = ...;
  const z: Type3<ComplexParam1, ComplexParam2, ComplexParam3> = ...;
}
```

If I could use spread operator for type parameters, I could avoid the duplication:

```
type ComplexParams = [ComplexParam1, ComplexParam2, ComplexParam3];

f(x: Type1<...ComplexParams>) {
  const y: Type2<...ComplexParams> = ...;
  const z: Type3<...ComplexParams> = ...;
}
```

But this syntax doesn't work. Is there another way to achieve something similar?

Comment: You can redefine `Type1`, `Type2`, and `Type3` to take tuples instead, but if you're only invoking them this way once in your code base then you don't gain anything. So that depends on your use case.  There is a feature request at [ms/TS#39648](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39648) you might want to add your  to.  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the feature request link. I was mostly wondering if there is a way to gain something after all that I didn't know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to this is by using [Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/tuples) and [Index Access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) as follows. This might save some code as you only have to define your `ComplexParams` once.

```
type Type1<A, B, C> = any;
type Type2<A, B, C> = any;
type Type3<A, B, C> = any;

type ComplexParam1 = any;
type ComplexParam2 = any;
type ComplexParam3 = any;

type ComplexParams = [ComplexParam1, ComplexParam2, ComplexParam3];

function f(x: Type1<ComplexParams[0], ComplexParams[1], ComplexParams[2]>) {
  let y: Type2<ComplexParams[0], ComplexParams[1], ComplexParams[2]>;
  let z: Type3<ComplexParams[0], ComplexParams[1], ComplexParams[2]>;
}
```

or refactor `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` to accept a single tuple argument instead of three separate [generic arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) (and later access it's individual types ->  same principle).

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYA8BBANFAQhgwgPigF4oBDAOxAG4AoUSWeAJlQ2ynyNIprujkgDMLLLgLFyVarXjsA9gFswAGwgAPAAokATiXkJOEnjJwLlazTvmMD3afROKVG7boE3Jd6A7PPLAZ04AbW8nC10EXFNQlytIx3MYgQBdGmoAMwBXMgBjYABLWTIoNIAKVQAuBkhkEIT-QIAGJLifMPk-QIRmuXjfXQ7GJLwASigAb2ooKBVgKBBK-ghmWr72xu6Vto6uluj6wbwaKZmoAC8F%20CFNmI6m3br%20zo2oh7WDmgBfIA)